# Less CSS: is it possible to access a constant in a parametric mixin

Tags: less

Let me explain what I mean by "constant" because I'm unsure of the correct terminology.

```
.state(pressed) {
    // Do something inside my mixin with "pressed"
}
```

In the example above, "pressed" is the constant - it's not a variable and cannot change.

The question is can I reference a pointer to this keyword inside the mixin?

```
.state(pressed) {
    .call-another-mixin(// use "pressed" without explicitly typing it //);
}
```

Comment: You just define `pressed` outside of the mixin as a variable and use it. I am not sure what you are trying to do or what troubles you are having but it looks like you are over complicating things

Comment: @Huangism - no doubt I'm over-complicating things - I always do, but it's more out of interest. I don't want to set a variable, outside as there are specific requirements for each state - one mixin does not fit all!

Comment: Ok, but if you want a value that don't change then it's just a variable that you don't change. Can you give more detail as in what you are trying to achieve? I don't really understand what you are trying to do or the use case of it

Comment: It is not. There's special `@arguments` variable but it does not work with explicitly specified parameter values (on the other hand, even if `@arguments` would work I'd personally still use `pressed` in this case as it's a "false DRY" situation).